# matlab plot zoom automatically in script

Tags: matlab

I would like to zoom a particular range in MATLAB subplot.

For example:

```
xzoom = 1:end; 
yzoom = 10;
```

I want the script to zoom automatically, only the above mentioned ranges.

I have tried this this code:

```
hZoom = zoom(gcf);
figure;plot(magic(10)); hCMZ = uicontextmenu;
hZMenu = uimenu('Parent',hCMZ,'Label','Switch to pan',...
'Callback','pan(gcbf,''on'')');
 hZoom = zoom(gcf);
set(hZoom,'UIContextMenu',hCMZ);
zoom('on').

hZMenu = uimenu('Parent',hCMZ,'Label','Switch to pan',...
'Callback','pan(gcbf,''on'')');
```

This gives the lens for me to zoom, but I don't want this. I want it to display the zoomed portion automatically.  How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always just change the axis range manually, like so:

```
data = magic(10);
xmin = 1;
xmax = size(data, 1);
ymin = 10;
ymax = 10;
hPlot = plot(data);
axis(hPlot, [xmin xmax ymin ymax])
```

I tried to fit the values of y and x min and max to your question but you can change them as needed.